# How do I name a Tensorflow model to be used in Tensorflow Serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

When executing the tensorflow_model_server binary it requires a model name command line argument, `model_name`.

How do I specify the name of the model during training so I can specify it when running tensorflow_model_server?

example: `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=model --model_base_path=../models/model/version/`

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like you can actually give your model a name with the command line argument `model_name` and it does not have to match anything from the tensorflow graph.

From the source code:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc#L41
`To specify model name (default "default"): --model_name=my_name`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the model name is only for identification when a client make a request to the server.

I'm currently testing Tensorflow Serving assigning the model name with:

```
--model_name="My_Model_Name"
```